# Recovering data from a drive on which a partition table has been created

Tags: mount, partition, partition-table, gdisk

I have 2 drives on my computer, and was running out of space in one due to 2 OS on the one with smaller capacity. I was trying to partition the larger one(which has data on it), and looking up tutorials, I went with using gdisk and the first step was creating a partition table. Once I did this, the drive was no longer mounted (I assume because technically no partitions existed on the drive, thus the partition table was empty and therefore there was effectively "nothing") and when trying to make a partition, I was afraid of erasing the data so I decided to check on google for how to proceed. It seems that most tutorials assume that you are working with a fresh drive or at least that you have the intention of formatting it after partitioning, so I have not been able to find a source which helps me save my data. Is there a way for me to do so or is my data toast? Here are some outputs of some commands that might be of interest:

(in gdisk)

```
Command (? for help): p   
Disk /dev/sda: 1953525168 sectors, 931.5 GiB
Model: ST1000LM035-1RK1
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/4096 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 092FF04B-CCED-45DA-81B9-7EEA1FD00FF8
[...]
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 1953525134
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 1953525101 sectors (931.5 GiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
```

(empty, as you can see)

```
user@local:/$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 092FF04B-CCED-45DA-81B9-7EEA1FD00FF8
```

(and other drives were listed that I assumed unnecessary for this discussion)

```
user@local:/$ sudo blkid
/dev/sda: PTUUID="092ff04b-cced-45da-81b9-7eea1fd00ff8" PTTYPE="gpt"
```

(No UUID, just PTUUID)

I've tried mounting the drive (as it is clearly a listed block device) but this doesn't seem to work. I get a "bad fs/option/superblock, missing codepage or helper program, or other error" error. Also it seems that creating a filesystem will also wipe my drive. I'm not sure what else to try so I hope someone could point me in a clear direction, thanks in advance!

Comment: If you erased partitions, you have to try to restore them. Does testdisk show partitions? http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk If you know apporx. what partitions were by sector, you can use parted rescue. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery

Comment: It wasn't parted to begin with (unless I'm not sure how it works, maybe it was all one big partition). While trying to make a partition, I ran into this issue.

Comment: Did you format the drive, not create & format a partition? Almost all tools expect drives to have partitions. If you formatted drive it is like a very large floppy drive and then any creation of partitions would damage some of the data.

Comment: I could have sworn I posted a comment about how the TestDisk solution working. I never formatted the drive, just created a gpt partition table and never created an actual partition. The previous partition table was no longer active it seems, and when I was trying to create a partition in the new table, I would get a warning about how my data would be lost. TestDisk found the other inactive partition and restored it, and with it, access to all my files.